# TryValidateObject not returning results on Range

Tags: c#, validation, data-annotations, custom-validators

I'm trying to leverage the DataAnnotations.Validator outside of MVC. I have two services that validate their respective models. Both models inherit from a Base class I wrote that had a `ValidateModel()` method.

```
public class BaseValidatableDomainModel : IValidatableDomainModel
{
    public BaseValidatableDomainModel()
    {
        ModelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
    }

    public ModelStateDictionary ModelState { get; set; }

    public virtual void ValidateModel()
    {
        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(this, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, results);
        foreach (var thisInvalidResult in results)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(thisInvalidResult.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault(),thisInvalidResult.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a test for each service that verifies the service behaves correctly when the data is invalid. The one model correctly errors for `PhoneNumber == null`:

```
[Required]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
```

However, the other model does not error when `CompanyId` is 0. CompanyId is defined as this:

```
public class CompanyAddressDomainModel : BaseValidatableDomainModel
{
    // Other fields
    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Company is required")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public AddressInputDomainModel Address { get; set; }
}
```

The code calls validation like this:

```
CompanyAddressDomainModel companyAddress = // set values

companyAddress.ValidateModel();
if (!companyAddress.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return companyAddress;
}
```

Why would it catch some validation, and not others? As far as I can tell, the two services and models are defined the same. If more information is needed, please let me know.

If I test with `CompanyId == 0` and `Address == null` I do see the address error, but not the CompanyId error.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I have to tell TryValidateObject to validate all.

```
public static bool TryValidateObject(
    object instance,
    ValidationContext validationContext,
    ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults,
    bool validateAllProperties
)
```

Like this:

```
Validator.TryValidateObject(this, validationContext, results, true);
```